# Is there a way to use @OrderColumn when @ManytoOne is the owning side?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I found that `@OrderColumn` works only in the cases of

- OneToMany is unidirectional relation
- OneToMany is the owning side (which is not recommended)

otherwise the order column just takes nulls.

Is that true, or there is a way to use `@OrderColumn` when `@ManytoOne` is the owning side?

Answer (score 1):

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-list) both unidirectional and bidirectional cases should be supported. But it looks like due to the [HHH-13287](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13287) you have a problem with bidirectional `@OneToMany` and `@OrderColumn`.