# @OrderColumn causes null elements in collection after update

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I'm trying to maintain order of bi-directionally mapped collection. Mapping like:

```
@Entity
public class Plate {
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "plate")
    @OrderColumn
    private List<W> wells = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}
```

And reverse mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Well {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "plate_id")
    private Plate plate;
}
```

The firs time I save the `Plate` entity the collection of 96 `Well`s everything is saved correctly and the `order` column is populated in database starting at 0 going up to 95. All good.

After subsequent update to `Plate` entity though (without really changing any of the `Well`) and save I see bunch of updates to the `order` column in DB resulting in the 96 elements be indexed starting from 97 going to 193.

As a result after next load of such collection the `List` contains 97 `null` elements followed by the expected 96 real elements (the list now has 193 elements in total).

The catch is the *bug* (?) doesn't reveal itself when you are debugging through it as probably some lazy collection gets loaded during the debugging so it is extremely difficult to tell what is the root cause.

I understand this is *probably* driven somehow by `AbstractCollectionPersister` and its `baseIndex` property but can't figure out wha may lead Hibernate into reindexing collection and starting from 97 instead of 0.

** Edit: ** Env
Hibernate 5.4.18.Final
Spring boot 2.2.9

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: updated the question with env info

Comment: It looks like the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256680/is-there-a-way-to-use-ordercolumn-when-manytoone-is-the-owning-side) question.